# Constraint a generic place holder to other generic place holder

Tags: swift, generics, constraints

I want to constraint U to T, is it possible?

```
protocol Pro {}
struct ST<T: Pro, AnyObject> {
    var anArr = [T]()
}
```

I know I can:

```
extension ST {
    // work
    func anElmFromArr<U: Pro>(at index: Int) -> U? {
        return anArr[index] as? U
    } 
}
```

But I want to constraint like this:

```
extension ST {
    // doesn't work.
    func anElmFromArr<U: T>(at index: Int) -> U? {
        return anArr[index] as? U
    }

    // it also doesn't work.
    func anElmFromArr<U>(at index: Int) -> U? where U: T {
        return anArr[index] as? U
    }
}
```

Comment: `T` is not a protocol

Comment: Why not simply `func anElmFromArr(at index: Int) -> T { anArr[index] }`?

Comment: Not possible. You can't specify a generic parameter as a type constraint.